# CAPL: Combining variables

Tags: vector, capl, canoe

In my CAPL script I have two variables A and B. For example sake, A=9 and B=7. Is there a way to make a third variable C and have C=97. In other words I’m not multiplying or adding A and B, I want to literally put them side by side to form a new variable. Is this possible to “combine” values like this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Same as in all other programming languages: convert to string and concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are always single digits (less than 10):
C = A*10+B